# How do I make an element be the maximum height it can be without causing the page to scroll?

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I have a dialog box:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui overlay fullscreen modal">
  <div class="header">
    Dialog box
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui warning message">
      <div class="header">
        Be careful
      </div>
      This is a warning message
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blueviolet">This is the container.<br />This is the container.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui approve button">Save</div>
    <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the purple div (the one that says "This is the container") to have the largest height possible without making the page scroll, like this:

[image: How the dialog box should work]

I've tried using `height:100%`, but it doesn't do anything. How can I get the result in the picture without using a pixel value for the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the container (`.content`) a flex container in column direction.

Add `flex: 1` to the purple box.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.ui.modal > .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ui.modal > .content > div:last-child {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
.ui.modal > .content {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ui.modal > .content > div:last-child {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.7.6/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class="ui overlay fullscreen modal">
  <div class="header">
    Dialog box
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ui warning message">
      <div class="header">
        Be careful
      </div>
      This is a warning message
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blueviolet">This is the container.<br />This is the container.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui approve button">Save</div>
    <div class="ui cancel button">Cancel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```